# Closure in the return type for a Rust function

Tags: rust

I wrote the following Rust program to print out only command-line arguments that are integers. It works perfectly:

```
use std::env;
fn main() {
    for i in env::args().filter_map(|arg| arg.parse::<i32>().ok()) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

I then attempted to re-write the program to abstract the filter into a function. This version does not compile.

```
use std::env::Args;
use std::env;
use std::iter::FilterMap;
// Version 2
fn main() {
    for i in nums(&env::args()) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}

fn nums<F: Fn(String) -> Option<i32>>(args: &Args) -> FilterMap<Args,F> {
    args.filter_map(|arg| arg.parse::<i32>().ok())
}
```

It produces the following compilation errors:

```
   Compiling iterator_return_type v0.1.0 (file:///Users/gabriel/AllProjects/SentimentAnalysis/iterator_return_type)
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:16:9
   |
16 |     for i in nums(&env::args()) {
   |         ^ cannot infer type for `_`

error: the type of this value must be known in this context
  --> src/main.rs:22:27
   |
22 |     args.filter_map(|arg| arg.parse::<i32>().ok())
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:22:21
   |
22 |     args.filter_map(|arg| arg.parse::<i32>().ok())
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found closure
   |
   = note: expected type `F`
              found type `[closure@src/main.rs:22:21: 22:50]`

error: aborting due to previous error(s)

error: Could not compile `iterator_return_type`.
```

What I find particularly confusing is the final compilation error. I do not understand how else I might specify a closure type.

Thanks!

Comment: The solution given in that problem does not work for my example. In that problem, the Split iterator was the return type. The FilterMap iterator requires a closure type parameter. This is a completely different problem.

Comment: You should seriously consider renaming the question's title, since it heavily suggests being a duplicate of the one suggested above. You seem to have more of a "cannot refer to a closure type" problem.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks! I have done so.

Comment: @GabrielFerrer, It is the same problem. Compiler do not infer return types of functions by looking at their code, so you must provide full return type yourself, but you can't do it, because type of closure is anonymous. Thus you need to resort to the methods in the answer I pointed to. Like [boxed trait-object](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=711f21acb2437f661937cf538e0dbc6a&version=stable&backtrace=0), for example.

Comment: @red75prime: While the solution in the answer pointed works, it does *not* mention anything about closures and notably does not explain the crucial issue that while for iterators this is just sugar, for closures it is mandatory since they are Voldemort types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`impl Trait` and `Box<Trait>` solution can be applied to both iteratorsand closures, both of them are just traits! The difference is you *have to* use them in the closure case.

If you want to use `impl Trait`, then your code will look like this (note that `Args` should be passed by value):

```
#![feature(conservative_impl_trait)]

use std::env::Args;
use std::env;
use std::iter::FilterMap;

fn main() {
    for i in nums(env::args()) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}

fn nums(args: Args) -> FilterMap<Args, impl FnMut(String) -> Option<i32>> {
    args.filter_map(|arg| arg.parse::<i32>().ok())
}
```

However, you usually need not expose the detail of the iterator type; therefore you can do it like this way:

```
fn nums(args: Args) -> impl Iterator<Item = i32> {
    args.filter_map(|arg| arg.parse::<i32>().ok())
}
```

What if you want to use stable Rust? Unfortunately you'll have to use boxing for now.

```
fn nums(args: Args) -> Box<Iterator<Item = i32>> {
    Box::new(args.filter_map(|arg| arg.parse::<i32>().ok()))
}
```

Why can't you describe a full type of closures, despite that you can describe an iterator like `Zip<Drain<'a, i32>, IntoIter<&'b str>>`? There are two reasons:

- Closure types are anonymous by nature; you'll have to anonymize (`impl Fn()`) or box (`Box<Fn()>`) them if you want to return them.
- The interface for closure traits is unstable; you can't implement them (`impl Fn() for YourType { .. }`) stably.

Then why doesn't your code work? The reason is:

- If you want to pass closures *to* a function, the *caller* decides its type. In this case you can write `fn foo<T: Fn()>() { .. }`.
- If you want to pass closures *from* a function, the *callee* decides its type. In this case you'll have to use `impl Trait`.

[RFC 1951](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1951-expand-impl-trait.md) will change this distinction. You will be able to use `impl Trait` in both cases.

Comment: And another excellent answer! I wish to welcome you on the Rust tag, and I am looking forward to your future contributions! Regarding the point about "anonymous" types, the programming community seems to be converging on the term "Voldemort types" for such types that shall not be named (cannot, really).